# Append records on every run;

Tags: sas

I have two macro variables.

```
%let subject=english;
%let task=easy;

data new;
    subject ="&subject";
    task = "&task";
run;
```

If I run the above code, I will have this dataset:

```
subject   task
english   easy
```

What I want is each time I run it, it needs to append new records. For example, if I run this code thrice my result should be.

```
subject  Task
english  Easy
english  Easy
english  Easy
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of possibilities, I sugguest two of them.

PROC APPEND

```
%let subject=english;
%let task=easy;

data tmp;
    subject ="&subject";
    task="&task";
run;

proc append base=new data=tmp;
run;
```

PROC SQL

```
%let subject=english;
%let task=easy;

proc sql;
    insert into new (subject, task) values ("&subject", "&task");
quit;
```